# Xelatex: Font shape `T3/lmr/m/n' undefined(Font) using `T3/cmr/m/n' instead(Font) for symbol `textsecstress'

Tags: installing-fonts

When I use xelatex compile the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

     [\textsecstress h\textopeno m\textschwa\textprimstress\textdyoghlig in\i\textschwa s]

\end{document}
```

there are two warnings:

1. `` Font shape `T3/lmr/m/n' undefined(Font) using `T3/cmr/m/n' instead(Font) for symbol `textsecstress' ``;
2. `Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.`

But if I choose `pdflatex` to compile this code, there is no warning. I want to remove these warnings with the `xelatex` compiler. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These warnings are innocuous. You can remove them, though:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{tipa}

\iftutex
  \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T3}{\rmdefault}{cmr}
\fi

\begin{document}

[\textsecstress h\textopeno m\textschwa\textprimstress\textdyoghlig in\i\textschwa s]

\end{document}
```

The font substitution cannot be done with `pdflatex`, because it would lead to an infinite loop, so it's necessary to do it conditionally. The conditional `\iftutex` is true when using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Note: see edit history for a previous solution using the `substitutefont` package, now declared obsolete.